# Error installing CNTK on win10 via scripted install

Tags: cntk

I have been trying to install the CNTK via scripted install on windows 10 and have come across a strange error.

I got the install from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cognitive-toolkit/Setup-CNTK-on-your-machine

CNTK-2-7-Windows-64bit-GPU.zip

I was kind of expecting the install to work out of the box, has anyone come across any similar errors? Am I missing something simple here?

Thanks,

[image: Initial Error]

[image: Initial Error]

When attempting to run the install again I get the following:

[image: Second Error]

[image: Third Error]

Comment: Experienced the same result on 2 machines now :(

Comment: maybe you want to consider using pip install instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to get it all running by doing the pip install as suggested by @snowflake. thank you.

There was still a number of steps I needed to perform, which I will list below.

**Preparation.**

*Get Anaconda.*

from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cognitive-toolkit/setup-windows-python?tabs=cntkpy26#anaconda3
https://repo.continuum.io/archive/Anaconda3-4.1.1-Windows-x86_64.exe

*Get Instructions.*

https://microsoft.github.io/CNTK-R/articles/installation.html

*Get wheel location.*

cntk 2.7 from
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cognitive-toolkit/setup-windows-python?tabs=cntkpy26#anaconda3

3.5 CPU-Only    https://cntk.ai/PythonWheel/CPU-Only/cntk-2.7.post1-cp35-cp35m-win_amd64.whl
GPU https://cntk.ai/PythonWheel/GPU/cntk_gpu-2.7.post1-cp35-cp35m-win_amd64.whl

*Get CUDA.*

https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-90-download-archive?target_os=Windows&target_arch=x86_64&target_version=10&target_type=exenetwork

*Get CNTK*

I got the install from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cognitive-toolkit/Setup-CNTK-on-your-machine

CNTK-2-7-Windows-64bit-GPU.zip

**Installation.**

- Install anaconda3.
- open cmd prompt in admin mode
- navigate to c:\anaconda3\
- create anaconda virtual environment: **conda create -n cntk-py35 python=3.5 anaconda**
- activate environment: **activate cntk-py35**
- install cntk: **pip install https://cntk.ai/PythonWheel/GPU/cntk_gpu-2.7.post1-cp35-cp35m-win_amd64.whl**

**Running.**

when running c# example: Cntk.Core.CSBinding-2.8-rc0.dev20200201.dll not found...

Actual fix before it started working:

- copy all dll files from "CNTK-2-7-Windows-64bit-GPU\cntk\cntk" into bin of project
- change solution to x64 explicitly
  https://github.com/microsoft/CNTK/issues/3369
  It looks as if you need to set the x64 on the solution via the Configuration manager, not the project.

Comment: Thanks for sharing the details steps! I'm sure others will find it useful :)